redundancy of 13.1.28 in Abramowitz and Stegun
Eq. (13.1.27) of Abramowitz and Stegun says that
$$ {}_1F_1(a, b, z) = \exp{(z)}{}_1F_1(b-a,b,-z)$$
Eq. (13.1.28) in the same book says:
$$ $z^{1-b} {}_1F_1(1+a-b, 2-b, z) = z^{1-b}\exp{(z)}{}_1F_1(1-a,2-b,-z)$$
Does (13.1.28) follow from (13.1.27)? By setting the $a$ in (13.1.27) to be $1+a-b$ and the $b$ in (13.1.27) to be $2-b$? And multiplying both sides by $z^{1-b}$?
In that case, why is there a separate property here? Or am I missing something here?

It certainly looks like it, but maybe the context tells why we need the second version. I mean, when I teach trigonometry, I also write $$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$ and right underneath $$\tan^2(x)+1=\sec^2(x)$$ although (or because!) the second just follows from the first via dividing by $\cos^2(x)$. I mean, a lot of formulae "follow" from other formulae, but that does not make them redundant.

Also see Eq. 13.1.14 and 13.1.15: these forms are two of the eight solutions.

@Ramashalanka thank you. Does this mean that  $$ {}_1F_1(a, b, z) = \exp{(z)}{}_1F_1(b-a,b,-z) =  z^{1-b} {}_1F_1(1+a-b, 2-b, z) = z^{1-b}\exp{(z)} {}_1F_1(1-a,2-b,-z)$$? That is, all four equalities hold? I am not sure.

The actual question aside.. There are redundancies in A&S and G&R. Sometimes certain forms of identities are specifically useful and get their own attention in these reference texts. I wouldn't worry about it so much.

The confluent hypergeometric functions are solutions of Kummer's equation. As it's a second order equation, it has two linearly independent solutions. You can write these as $M(a,b,z)={}_1F_1(a,b,z)$ and $U(a,b,z)$. There are eight solutions, as in 13.1.12-13.1.19, but not all of them are linearly independent. The easiest way of seeing that is from 13.1.3 which says
$$U(a,b,z)=c_1 M(a,b,z) + c_2 z^{1-b}M(1+a-b,2-b,z).$$
You can pick any two of those three as linearly independent solutions (except for edge cases such as $b=1$). The relation 13.1.27 shows that 13.1.12 and 13.1.14 are equal, and 13.1.28 shows that 13.1.15 and 13.1.17 are equal, but 13.1.3 says that $M(a,b,z)$ and $z^{1-b}M(1+a-b,2-b,z)$ are generally linearly independent, otherwise $U(a,b,z)$ would not be linearly independent of $M(a,b,z)$.
